# MySQL:"Access denied to x@localhost' using python

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to connect MySQL using python. It connected in WorkBench MySQL. Then in the cmd, I tried to connect as well (shows as below). It worked well!

```
mysql -u MyNewPass
```

**However, when I ran the python code:**

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="MyNewPass", db="test", port=3306)
```

It showed the errors

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="MyNewPass", db="test", port=3306)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 74, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 170, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Can anyone help me about that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, a user is identified by the username ( 'root' ) and the host the user is connecting from.

In MySQL on Linux, the hostname "localhost" is special, it specifies a connection through a local socket, not a TCP/IP connection.

It looks like DNS hostname resolution is enabled ( the `--skip-name-resolve` option is not specified for the MySQL server)

Looks like MySQL server is seeing a connection coming from IP address 127.0.0.1, then doing a reverse lookup, and finding hostname "localhost", and then looking for a matching user 'root'@'localhost'.

(That explanation seems a bit odd to me, but I don't have any other explanation for the behavior, given the Python connect is specifying MySQL server IP address of 127.0.0.1, and the error message reporting 'root'@'localhost'.)

---

Some suggestions:

Try forcing a TCP/IP connection rather than a local socket connection. With MySQL command line client, we would specify `--protocol=TCP` e.g.

```
mysql ... --protocol=TCP ...
```

I'm not sure the exact syntax for the Python connector, but I expect it would be very similar.

Or, try specifying hostname of "localhost" to use local socket connection.

Check the contents of mysql.user table for users that have 'root' as username

```
SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root'
```

Note that the password for 'root'@'%' can be different than 'root'@'localhost', because those are *different* users.

---

What is really confusing is that it looks like the connection has supplied IP address 127.0.0.1 as destination host, and that seems like it should force a TCP connection. But MySQL appears to be reporting an error attempting connection using a unix socket.

Reported behavior is very strange. I'm not sure what's going on with the Python connector to cause `127.0.0.1` to be interpreted as a localhost socket connection.

Here's a reference to the expected behavior:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name **localhost** specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to **localhost**, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. When I didn't add the passwd, it worked. I am not sure why??!!!!